# iphone - Block input variables question

Tags: iphone

I am trying to understand how string1/string2 in the block are being fed input values from stringsArray in this code snippet. i don't see a place where these values are pointing to strngsArray. here is the code -

```
NSArray *stringsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 @"string 1",
                                 @"String 21",
                                 @"string 12",
                                 @"String 11",
                                 @"String 02", nil];

static NSStringCompareOptions comparisonOptions = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch |
        NSWidthInsensitiveSearch | NSForcedOrderingSearch;
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

NSComparator finderSortBlock = ^(id string1, id string2) {

    NSRange string1Range = NSMakeRange(0, [string1 length]);
    return [string1 compare:string2 options:comparisonOptions range:string1Range locale:currentLocale];
};

NSArray *finderSortArray = [stringsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:finderSortBlock];
NSLog(@"finderSortArray: %@", finderSortArray);



/*
Output:
finderSortArray: (
    "string 1",
    "String 02",
    "String 11",
    "string 12",
    "String 21"
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array will feed the objects it contains to the block one after another to determine the order.

Comment: stringsArray is being fed in this line - NSArray *finderSortArray = [stringsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:finderSortBlock];

Comment: so, you mean this line is feeding stringsArray to the block; is there a reference to this sort of syntax where paramter is in front of the function name;

Comment: Yes, of course. Isn't it reasonable to assume that the method `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` is responsible for calling your block with the correct arguments? After all, that is the method you are passing the block to.